# Charting for Windows Store apps ( XAML C#)

Tags: windows-8, charts

I am looking for references or samples on charting options in Windows 8 XAML/C#. 
I will also consider any third party options.

I need to provide a charting solution include bar graphs, pie charts and line graphs

Answer (score 4):

You can take a took to the charts available in the free [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try telerik

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls.aspx

If that's looks expensive, you can build something yourself based on the blog article below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/metroapps/archive/2012/07/24/building-pie-chart-for-windows-8-metro.aspx

Arun

Answer (score 0):

I have been involved in the porting of Visiblox to WinRT. We currently have a beta release out, and will make a full release in the next couple of weeks.

http://www.visiblox.com/visibloxcharts-for-winrt